# Unable to get 1Gbps Connection Speed

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

My Connection Speed properties are limited up to to 100Mbps instead of 1Gbps.

Router Model: TP-Link AC1200
Internet subscription: 300Mbps
Connectivity: Wired

*Info: I have conceal my UTP Cat.6 cable via my wall and ceiling between Living Hall to Room.*

**So my situation is by sequence below:**

1. From the Router I am using UTP Cat.5e cable connected to the Wall
   Socket (the panel is stated Cat.5e).
2. At the Wall Socket (Living), in between is using UTP Cat.6 cable
   from Living Hall to Room.
3. At Room: I am using UTP Cat.5e connected to the Laptop.

Unfortunately, I just get up to 100Mbps at the Speed Connection.

I have tried to connect using same UTP Cat.5e directly from Router to Laptop and getting 1Gbps at Speed Connection perfectly.

**Connectivity 1**
Router -> UTP Cable Cat.5e -> Wall Patch Panel In-Out (using UTP Cat.6) -> UTP Cable Cat.5e -> Laptop
Result: 100Mbps

**Connectivity 2**
Router -> UTP Cable Cat.5e -> Laptop
Result: 1Gbps

I expected to have a 1Gbps Connection Speed in my Room via wired using **Connectivity 1**.

Comment: A common problem is that 10Base-T (10 Mbps) and 100Base-TX (100 Mbps) only require two pairs, so many cables (incorrectly) do not have or connect all four pairs, or they use two pairs for each of two connections. Unfortunately, 1000Base-T (1 Gbps) requires all four pairs, and it will negotiate to 100Base-TX if it doesn't have all four pairs.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have [split pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_pair) in your in-wall wiring.

Decide between [T568A or T568B termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568#T568A_and_T568B_termination) for your in-wall wiring to use, and make sure both ends comply with whichever one you picked.

The wires connected to pins 3 & **6** must be a twisted pair. If you paired pin 3 with 4, and then paired pin 5 with 6, then you have split pairs. It's a common mistake. Split pairs defeats the ability of Ethernet's [differential signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling) to cancel out common mode interference.

Note that a simple pinout tester won't find this wiring flaw, because it can only tell which pins connect to which pins at the other end, not whether the wires in the middle where twisted together with the correct other wires.

Also make sure you have all 4 pairs (all 8 wires) terminated properly, and that you have continuity on all 8 wires. 100 Megabit Ethernet (100BASE-TX) only uses two pairs, whereas Gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE-T) requires all 4 pairs. So if you have pins 1, 2, 3, and 6 wired correctly, but problems with any of the other pins, that would cause 100BASE-TX to work, but 1000BASE-T to fail.

Answer (score 2):

I would get a wire tester and test this portion of your setup:

Wall Patch Panel In-Out (using UTP Cat.6)

It looks like your simply getting Attenuation on the wire, so test the cable going from the Patch panel to your room. It might need to simply be re-punched.

Comment: Yup. And when you do it, check the split pair issue mentioned in Spiff's excellent answer.

Answer (score -1):

This issue still seems valid today. Direct wired ethernet connections perform at 1Gbps. However, connecting through an access point, still limits speed to 100Mbps in some cases.

My experience was the same, 2.4GHz at ~100Mbps.

When I switched to 5GHz on the same device (once it actually supported it) I had issues. So, I followed a guide to set my channel width uniquely. https://www.asus.com/us/support/faq/1011431/  That being said, instead of 20/40/60MHz I set it to a static 80 (hoping any local wireless congestion would disappear). Voila, at 5Ghz the speed jumped up to nearly 1Gbps (limited around 850Mbps). Note: My device has a pair of 2-ohm antennas (originally intended for bluetooth on one and wifi on the other), not sure if it teams both for 5Ghz, but I got the 5Ghz I wanted on an old windows laptop upgraded with a beefier business battery, SSD, and 32Gb of ram on Windows 11; and this compares to a newer 2014 Macbook. I don't think you need all of that, but I added them to improve software testing, not Wifi.

To get 5Ghz, I installed a compatible Wifi 6e chip with newer bluetooth, but I poorly wired the two external 8-ohm antennas--I only got 100Mbps on the 6GHz. Despite success at 5Ghz, I have not tried again. However, in the meantime, I  set the bandwidth to a fixed 160Hz, but doubt I need to at 6Ghz since it is new. Next, I need to repair the 8-ohm antennas. I damaged one during install, and need to modify the other to clear the motherboard. That being said I switched back to the 2-Ohm atennas, and now I get 60Mbps on 6Ghz. Soon I will solder the wire on the 8-ohm, and cut and solder the other, to test it out natively. Without the changes my fan brushes the wire, and I can't continue with a weak connection on the other.

For wired, Cat5e works fine at 1Gbps, and most modern hardware auto senses wire configuration. My 11 year-old helped me crimp the cable and we accidentally did straight pass through. However, I still got 1Gbps. Even when we patched back 150ft to the garage switch and back 120ft to another room.

The trick was to install routers, adapters, and unmanaged switches that support 1Gbps, including the modem. 1Gbps uses all 8-wires. Meaning, in one wall setup I had to install the other 4-wires inside the wall. I used a wiring diagram from online. The walls were wired for basic ethernet with only 4-wires. The rest were bundled around the cable in the wall. You can check that too.

Next I added IPv6 for application improvements, at the recommendation of a device, but that only worked after putting in all 8-wires in the wall (all Cat5e). Don't confuse the Cat5e going to the phone line though, just the RJ-45 ethernet jacks. Apparently Cat5e is cheaper than phone wire?